# Socket.io/Node.js and SSL

Tags: node.js, ssl, socket.io

I recently bought a SSL certificate from Comodo. They sent me these files:

```
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
PositiveSSLCA2.crt
mydomain.crt
```

I then created my private key and ca-bundle like so,

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out mydomain.key 1024
cat PositiveSSLCA2.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > mydomain.ca-bundle
```

This is the code I'm using to put it all together. I get an SSL connection error in Chrome.

```
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./mydomain.key').toString();
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('./mydomain.crt').toString();
var ca = fs.readFileSync('./mydomain.ca-bundle').toString();

var io = require('socket.io').listen(1200, { key:privateKey,cert:certificate,ca:ca });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generate your private key **before** you are issued a certificate.

A certificate is created when a CA signs the public key that goes with a particular private key.  You generate a private key, then you create a CSR which includes the public key.  The CA sends you back a certificate.

You must have generated a private key at some point before you got a certificate – you have to use that.  If you try to use a private key that you generate after the certificate is issued, it will obviously not match the public key in your certificate.

---

Also, node's `tls` module cannot parse certificate bundles.  You have to pass each certificate separately in an array.

```
{
    key: fs.readFileSync('mydomain.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('mydomain.crt'),
    ca: [ fs.readFileSync('AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt'), fs.readFileSync('PositiveSSLCA2.crt') ]
}
```

The [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener) have more detail.